# MVC3, Models, Create & Edit Hidden Fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, models, edit, hidden

I have a few models in my MVC3 web app that have fields that need to be set "behind the scenes" when a user creates or edits an object/entity.

I'm trying to figure out what the best practice is regarding these types of fields.

For example...

```
public class EntityA {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  ...
  [ForeignKey("User")]
  public int UpdatedBy_Id { get; set; }
  public virtual User UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

The create and edit views for this allow the user to edit the "Title" field, but the "UpdatedBy" field needs to be set by the app when the entity is inserted or updated.

Is it best to drop a hidden field on the views and set "UpdatedBy_Id" there, or use the model property "get/set" body to do so? ...or... Should this be on the HttpPost in the controller?

Comment: Can't you use the users session data (via membership or any provider) to retrive the updatedBy value in the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer to place fields like this outside of user control. Especially if they're integer fields a user can edit to make phony records. The choices then fall between using TempData(if session is enabled) or possibly retrieving it on the fly for the current user. If you're not worried about the user modifying them, then I'd go with a simple hidden field or placing it in the route values for the post, allowing the framework to do the work for you.

Comment: In this specific instance I can pull the value from Session, I'm just not sure where to intercept the entity and update the value. If I add a "set" body to the navigation property it wants me to also add the "get" body, and I don't know if that's what I should be doing.

Comment: @Kizmar well if you're using automatic properties, there isn't any value of having a set without a get. So I'm not sure what you're asking. Since the value can be pulled from the Session, then you can just let the framework fill out the user input for you, and you would fill out the rest before persisting the entity.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance on this. The "you would fill out the rest before persisting the entity" part is where I'm confused. If 90% of the properties are set by the framework when the HttpPost happens, where do I fill in the other 10%? I've tried doing so in the [HttpPost] Create(EntityA entity) method in the controller, but as soon as I try to modify the entity I get "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker." (Ex. doing something like "entity.UpdatedBy_Id = 1;")

Comment: ...Just figured out the error mentioned above. After many changes to the model, I'm now setting the "_id" property instead of trying to set the navigation property directly.

Answer (score 1):

This is where DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) come in handy.

Your view uses a DTO as it's model.  The DTO mirrors your entity object in terms of properties, but excludes properties which you don't want the user to be able to manipulate.

Then in your controller when you are ready to persist the Entity, you create a new Entity object, and take the properties from the DTO passed to the action and copy them to your Entity object.  It is at this point you can set the UpdatedBy property.

To make life easier when mapping properties from the Entity to the DTO (and vice versa), you can look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com), which will handle this automatically, if you use the same names for your properties.

If you just pass the Entity to the view, there is the potential for the user to change the values of properties that you don't want them to be able to.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use a hidden field and set the UpdatedBy_Id. It will then be posted back with the form and it can be databound like the rest of the information.

Comment: This works, only be aware that the user can change the value of the hidden field using Firebug or similar...